# CSS: Graphic centered, but then continue a pattern to the right

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

This is an odd one ... I need to display a graphic always that's always centred in the browser. Easy.

But the catch is that this graphic is part of some branding... and the branding demands that a line within the graphic continuously extend to the right for the duration of the browser width.

Example:

|---------[Logo]]]]]]]]]|

I thought I'd be able to center a DIV, create a `UL` and then just float the `LI` to the left ... but the issue becomes that because of the parent DIV width, the `LI` gets pushed down to the next line and I'm not sure how to stop that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the graphic whatever way you like and stick a div behind it with a top border on for the line. Position it absolutely and set the left:0 and right:50%.
Like so: (try resizing the browser window)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<div style="position:absolute; border-top:solid 1px #CCC; left:0; right:50%; z-index:0; margin-top:20px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="position:absolute; width:200px; margin-left:-150px; left:50%; z-index:1; background:#CCC; padding:25px">this is a logo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm always quite skeptical of z-index. Should I be? This needs to work with mobile browsers as well...

Comment: No its pretty reliable - I usually float everything like you but I often integrate a bit of absolute stuff in there.

Comment: Another option is a combination of Jason's and my idea: have a div positioned absolutely as above (left 0 right 50%) with a right aligned image inside it. Then just add a background image to the div for your line.

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is that the logo needs to be centred at all times... not `left: 50%`.

Comment: The negative margin will center it perfectly - Just make it half the image's width

Comment: DUH!!! Man... that's what hours and hours of tedious work does to your brain, children.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple background images using CSS3.

Something like this

```
#header{
    background-image: url(images/logo.img), url(images/logo_line.img);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
}
```

More info here: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: This will work nicely but you'll have to make 2 images and it will only suit latest browsers.